# install PWA directly after using an URL (not by using the install button in chrome)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

i have installed chromium-x11 (yocto 2.6) on a raspberrypi3. From now, i can use some Progressive web app (PWA) like https://superpwa.com/.
Enable flags for PWA by writing this in chrome:
chrome://flags

To install it, just click on the button on the right-top corner of the google chrome page after using the URL.
However, i want the PWA to get installed automatically just after using the URL. In other words, i don't want to install the PWA by clicking on the button on the right-top corner of the google chrome page.

If anybody can tell me if it's possible and how, i would be so thanksfull.
Have a great day.

Comment: The only way to install a valid PWA is through the browser and the user must explicitly agree to the install prompt.

Comment: Thx, i'm gonna try adding the installation button directly in my pwa.